AP Physics 2: addition of electric potential
Try to help some high schooler.
In one chapter "Addition of Electric Potential" of Princeton Review of AP Physics 2, it says that because electric potential is scalar, it can be added (even though it may be positive or negative). That causes some issue of reasoning.
Suppose two charges, one positive q+ and one negative q-, are placed at fixed points in space. Consider the electric potential Vm at the mid-point. Since Vq+ is positive and Vq- is negative, adding them will render Vm = 0. However, intuitively this seems not true. When putting any test charge at the mid-point, it will tend to move indicating it has non-zero potential.
On the other hand, suppose both charges are either positive or negative. Then the mid-point potential Vm will not be zero by addition. However, a test charge at the mid-point will tend to stay indicating zero potential.
Can anyone help clarify this?

it will tend to move indicating it has non-zero potential That’s an incorrect conclusion. The force on a test charge has nothing to do with the value of the potential. It’s determined by the gradient (i.e.. the spatial rate of change) of the potential. Try graphing the potential. Where it has a slope, there is a nonzero field and there would be a force.

Let me make it simpler. What is Vm=? in the first case. Just give me your answer and preferably your reasoning behind it.

It’s zero halfway in between. You got that right. But it has a nonzero gradient there. You cannot compute the force from the value of the potential at one point.

The @Ghoster's comments provide a complete answer without equations or formulas since it seems  you ignore that the electrostatic force on an electric charge $:q:$ is $\mathbf F = q\mathbf E = -q\boldsymbol\nabla V$.

You may want to think about how this maps to gravitational potentials.
Your car doesn't roll because it has positive gravitational potential, it rolls because locally the road points downhill (to a lower potential).
If you decided to set your zero potential at Mean Sea Level, then you might drive down a hill into Death Valley.   At some point you would cross the 0 MSL potential, but would still experience a force pushing you further downhill.
This is analogous to a test charge at the 0 potential experiencing a force pushing it to a lower potential.

However, by saying Vm=0 it basically says no work is needed.

I'm not sure where you're getting that.   The zero potential is just an arbitrary point.   It takes energy to move from a lower potential to a higher potential.  Energy is released moving from a higher potential to a lower potential.    There's no difference between rolling downhill at an altitude of 3000 meters and rolling downhill at an altitude of zero meters.

Where does the kinetic energy comes from?

The kinetic energy comes from the rearrangement of the system.  When the system is rearranged into a state with lower potential energy, that energy is transformed.
The car gains kinetic energy by moving from a higher gravitational potential to a lower gravitational potential.
The test charge gains kinetic energy by moving from a higher electric potential to a lower electric potential.

I pick your answer only because it is not beyond a high schooler's understanding. Yet you still fail to explain. It takes work to bring the test particle to the mid-point. However, by saying Vm=0 it basically says no work is needed. If no work is needed, how come the particle can move? Where does the kinetic energy comes from?

@user180574 It takes work to bring the test particle to the mid-point. No. Why do you think that? In a comment on another answer, you wrote “Given the formula of the book, no work is needed”, so you aren’t even being consistent. If you don’t believe that the work is zero because the difference in potential is zero, then calculate $\int \vec F\cdot d\vec r$.

To clarify this, I want to be more explicit about the form of the potential (but one doesn't have to). In 1 dimension, a charge $q>0$ at the origin will have a coulomb potential (coulombs law) that looks like
$$ V = \frac{q}{|r|}$$ where I am ignoring prefactor constants for simplicity. A charge with value $-q$ located at $a$ will have potential $$ V = \frac{-q}{|r-a|}$$ Now, it is true that the resulting potential will be the superposition of these 2 so we have $$V = \frac{q}{|r|}-\frac{q}{|r-a|}$$ Will this be $0$ somewhere? Let's look at a plot of $V$ on the y-axis and $r$ on the x-axis.

It does have a $0$ at $a/2$, the midpoint, but what we need to realize is that the significant aspect of the potential with regards to motion is its gradient (derivative).
For instance, for two positive charges, the potential will look like this: 
which means that if a positive or negative charge is at the midpoint, it will not move (although, if the charge is negative, any nudge would cause it to accelerate towards one of the positive charges).
So in your example (the first plot), the charge will move if it is at the point where the potential is $0$, as per intuition, as the gradient of the potential is non-zero there.

Regarding your conclusion in the last sentence, where does the kinetic energy come from?

The electromagnetic field. Let me link details about this.

@user180574 where does the kinetic energy come from From the reduction in the potential energy as it moves in the direction of less PE.

Ghoster's answer is right. You have to think about the total potential energy (think of all 3 charges) and the energy will come from there.

@Ghoster, So Vm is not zero?

You have to think about the total potential ENERGY, not just the potential at that point. The potential at that point being $0$ doesn't contradict that because these are different quantities.

@user180574 Vm is zero in your example. However, the single value of Vm does not, and can not, matter.  You can always add an arbitrary constant value to the potential energy and the physics will not change. This is because the force is determined by the change in potential, not by the value of the potential. (In electrostatics we often set the zero of potential as "infinitely far away," but this is just a convention.)

@user180574 So Vm is not zero? I wrote “It’s zero halfway in between. You got that right.” I was referring to $V_m$ being zero. How did you conclude that I said it wasn’t zero?

@Ghoster, Let me rephase the problem from a different angle. How much work would it take to move a test charge from infinite distance to mid-point? Initially, its V is zero, and Vm is also zero. Given the formula of the book, no work is needed. Yet the test charge will move, so where does the kinetic energy come from?

@user180574 If you are confused about kinetic energy, you should ask a new question. This question didn’t even mention KE. You can’t just keep asking new questions in comments on answers.


Can anyone help clarify this?

Your test charge at the midpoint will accelerate because it experiences a force.
Force is the negative gradient of the potential energy $U=qV$:
$$
\vec F = -\vec \nabla U = -q\vec \nabla V\;,
$$
or, in one dimension:
$$
F = -\frac{dU}{dx} = -q\frac{dV}{dx}
\approx -q \frac{V_2 - V_1}{x_2 - x_1}\;.
$$
The force at the midpoint is:
$$
F(x_{mid}) = -q\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{V(x_{mid}+\delta) - V(x_{mid})}{\delta} = \left.-q\frac{dV}{dx}\right|_{x=x_{mid}}
$$
Therefore, you need to know the potential at two points (and take a limit) in order to determine the force. And it is the difference between these two potential values that determines the force.
In other words, the force is determined by the slope of the potential, not by the actual value of the potential.

To put this into equations, for the case of a point charge $-Q$ at position $x=-a$ and a point charge $+Q$ at position $x=+a$ and a test charge $q$ at position $x$, the potential is:
$$
V(x) = kQ\left(\frac{1}{|x-a|} - \frac{1}{|x+a|}\right)
$$
and indeed, at the midpoint $x=0$ we have $V(0)=0$.
However, the force is:
$$
kqQ\left(\frac{(x-a)}{|x-a|^3} - \frac{(x+a)}{|x+a|^3}\right)\;,
$$
which is not zero at $x=0$, but rather is $F(0)=kqQ\frac{-2a}{|a|^3}$.

Note further, that if I were to add an arbitrary contant value $C$ to the potential I would arrive at the same result. For, suppose I used a different potential $\tilde V = V + C$, then the resulting force is:
$$
\tilde F = -q\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{\tilde V(x_{mid}+\delta) - \tilde V(x_{mid})}{\delta} 
$$
$$
= -q\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{V(x_{mid}+\delta) + C - V(x_{mid}) - C}{\delta} 
$$
$$= -q\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{V(x_{mid}+\delta) - V(x_{mid})}{\delta} = \left.-q\frac{dV}{dx}\right|_{x=x_{mid}}
$$
$$=F\;.
$$
Thus, the actual value of the potential does not matter, only the limit of the difference of potential values matters to determine the force.
However, in electrostatics, we often agree to set the zero level of the potential to be "infinitely far aware." You can see this from an expression like:
$$
V = kQ/r\;,
$$
which goes to zero as $r\to\infty$.
